# Get Image URL from RSS feed

Tags: php, rss, feed

I want to get image URL from RSS feed, but I only can get title, url link, and description. Here is the feed link "http://www.hotkhmer.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss" . And here is my code:

```
function parse(){
$rss = simplexml_load_file($this->feed);    
$rss_split = array();   
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {    
  $title = (string) $item->title; // Title
  $link   = (string) $item->link; // Url Link
  $description = (string) $item->description; //Description           
  $rss_split[] = '
    <div>
        <a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" title="" >'.$title.'</a>
        <hr>
    </div>
    ';
}
return $rss_split;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as far a I can see there is no image element in the feed. The image is in the `description` if that is what you are after you are going to need to use `html_entity_decode` and then parse that with something like the php `DOMDocument` class to get the image tag out of it.

There is also an image in there with the tag `thumbnail`. Use that and then retrieve the `url` attribute using the array that `element->attributes()` returns.

It really does not make it easy that the xml you provided is minified...

Comment: have any way to select only image url ?

Comment: I explained it above dude. If you don't know how to iterate an array to find the key you are looking for then you should probably do some googling. for completeness sake what you are after is `$arr = element->attributes();` `$arr['url']`. See http://au1.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php it will help you out.

Comment: Also http://au2.php.net/domdocument . It is imperative you do research. Don't expect us to do your work for you - only point you in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, there is an image element in the feed. See my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I really stupid with this, I can't do this. Could you write it down, please!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code to get image src:**

```
$description = (string) $item->description; //Description
$html = $description;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
echo $tags[0]->getAttribute('src');
```

**some extra things:**

To remove image from description:

```
$description = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $description);
```

To remove iframe if coming with rss feed:

```
$description = preg_replace('/<iframe.*?\/iframe>/i','', $description);
```

To make description string short:

```
substr($description,0,200); //200 charcters
```

Answer (score -1):

The [RSS 2.0](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html) spec is explicit. The `image` element can be used to add an image to the feed at the channel level:

> Specifies a GIF, JPEG or PNG image that can be displayed with the
>   channel. [More info here](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html#ltimagegtSubelementOfLtchannelgt).

Comment: I think you completely missed the point there mate. The RSS feed already has an image in it. The OP is trying to get it out.

Comment: That's what I understood. Since it's in the <image> element, whatever he does for <title> applies.